# How to handle uninitialized local variables

Tags: c#, clr

After reading [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/10/12/absence-of-evidence-is-not-evidence-of-absence.aspx) Eric Lippert Article, I understand that the C# compiler doesn't like it if we leave **local** variables uninitialized.

As I encounter this 'problem' from time to time, I looked at some of my old code and was able to weed out most of the situation where actually don't need uninitialized (`SomeClass obj = null`) local variables.

But I came up with a situation where I don't know how to refactor the code.

```
public void DoSomething(string foo) {   

    SomeClass obj; // = null; 

    try {
        obj = SomeClass.CreateItem(target);
    } catch(CustomException ex) {
        // notify UI of error
    }

    if (obj != null) {
        // do something with `obj`
    }
}
```

`SomeClass.CreateItem` may fail due to external factors. If it does, I want to notify the user, if not I want to perform an Action.

The C# compiler doesn't want me to leave `obj` uninitialized, so I *usually* assign `null` to it.

This feels like a 'hack' now and my question is:

Is there a design flaw in the code above?

And if there is, how should I deal with references at compile time, when I can't determine if they are going to point to an existing object at run time?

Comment: The "reasoning" of the compiler is that, if there is an exception in SomeClass.CreateItem, obj will stay uninitialized when reaching the "obj!=null" test. The general principle is that a variable don't need to be initialized if it is necessarily assigned in the code, i.e. all conditional branches assign a value.

Answer (score 10):

I would refactor the code like this:

```
private SomeClass TryToCreateItem()
{
    try 
    {
        return SomeClass.CreateItem(target);
    } 
    catch(CustomException ex) 
    {
        // notify UI of error
    }
    return null;
}

public void DoSomething(string foo) 
{ 
    SomeClass obj = TryToCreateItem(); 
    if (obj != null) {
      // do something with `obj`
    }
```

"Extract method" is my favourite refactoring.

Comment: Wasn't it for a similar reason, that you'd refactor 'bool TryParse(string input, out int result)' or is that a different scenario, since TryParse typically deals with (non-nullable) value types?

Comment: @MrPaulch: You raise a good point; the null here is being used as a signal that the operation has failed. If you need to distinguish between three cases: fail/null, success/null and success/non-null, then you'd need some additional mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

The `// do something with`obj`` code *should be inside the `try` block`*.

What you're trying to do is run some code that may or may not succeed, and then run some other code *only if the previous code succeeded*.  That's generally a very strong sign that the other code is a part of the same logical block that is dependent on there not being an exception.  If there's an exception constructing this object you want this code to be skipped, which is exactly the behavior that you get by including it in the `try` block.

Comment: What if some portion of the `//do something` part is able to throw a `CustomException` aswell? Then I cannot identify what went wrong by catching alone. Essentially I have a conflicting convention in mind that says: "Keep your try blocks as tight as possible"

Comment: @MrPaulch Do you really want to do a completely different thing if something else throws that same exception?  If so, then it's a sign that they shouldn't both be throwing the same exception.  And I wouldn't say that it's a good idea to try to keep your try blocks tight.  Quite the opposite; when you see very tight `try` blocks it's a sign something is quite wrong.  They generally should be covering all of the operations representing some single logical operation.

Comment: Your point about 'different' Exceptions makes sense! One final question would be: What do I do if I need to return the object iff it exists or null if it doesn't?

Comment: @MrPaulch Return it inside of the `try`, and return `null` in the `catch`.

Answer (score 0):

You could refactor it to encapsulate all your code within the try/catch related to that object and if you *really* do need to do something if it fails then you can use a bool to relate that to the rest of your code:

```
    public void DoSomething(string foo)
    {

        bool failedCreation = false;

        try
        {
            SomeClass obj = SomeClass.CreateItem(target);
        }
        catch (CustomException ex)
        {
            // notify UI of error
            failedCreation = true;
        }

        if (failedCreation)
        {
            // do other stuff.
        }
    }
```

But this doesn't look like what you have in mind. I would just encapsulate everything within the try/catch and be done with it.